# Accessing a Dictionary from a Class other than the Main() Class in C#

Tags: c#

I've just started working with C# in January and am working on a simple game for a project. I have the Program.cs class which contains the Main() class, player.cs which contains the majority of actions that a player can take, and building.cs which holds the building a player can purchase.

building.cs

```
namespace Game
{
    public class building
    {
        public int price { get; }
        public bool owned { get; set; }
        public string? name { get; }
        public int owner { get; set; }

        public building(string name, int price, bool owned, int owner)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
            this.owned = owned;
            this.owner = owner;
        }
    }

    public class buildingDict
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, building> InitializeBuildings()
        {
            building wheatfield = new building("wheatfield", 4, false, 1);
            var buildings = new Dictionary<string, building>();
                buildings.add("wheatfield", wheatfield);
            return buildings; 
        }
    }

}
```

Now, I would like to be able to access this from my player.cs class, but it doesn't seem possible.

I can access it from Progam.cs Main()

```
namespace Game
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var ownedbuildings = buildingDict.InitializeBuildings();
        Console.WriteLine($"There are {ownedbuildings.Count} buildings for sale");
        Console.WriteLine($"{ownedbuildings["wheatfield"].name} is sold at ${ownedbuildings["wheatfield"].price}");
    }
}
```

Which returns

```
There are 1 buildings for sale
wheatfield is sold at $4
```

But when I attempt to access it from Player.cs I get errors and I'm not sure why or if it is even possible to access a Dictionary from a separate class that isn't Main().

```
namespace Game
{
    public class player
    {
        var OwnedBuildings = buildingDict.InitializeBuildings();

        public void purchasebuilding()
        {
            \\do something with the building dictionary.
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is on the `var` keyword which states, "The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear with a local variable declaration or in script code".

I would like to keep all the logic for what players can do to the player class solely and leave the mechanics of the game for the Main().

Comment: You get that error because `OwnedBuildings` is a field, and fields can’t be declared as `var`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intention is for each `player` to have their OWN, SEPARATE collection of buildings, but with the same default, initial setup, then use:

```
public class player
{

    private Dictionary<string, building> OwnedBuildings = buildingDict.InitializeBuildings();

    public void purchasebuilding()
    {
        //do something with the building dictionary.
    }

}
```

Comment: Idle_Mind, I went with your answer, though all the others were correct.  This is what I was looking for.  Each player will need to have their own separate collection of buildings.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a class constructor (like you did for building class) for the player that accepts just a dictionary object rather than trying to reference an external variable as a class property.

Then you could do

```
static void Main()
{
    var ownedbuildings = buildingDict.InitializeBuildings();
    var p = new player(ownedbuildings);
```

This may not be the best design, but it allows you to pass references between classes.

Comment: Thank you @OneCricketeer for your answer.  This method works, as  you know, but I went with another solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use "var" just inside of a class, in a class scope. The same way as you can not put any code that is doing something inside of a class too. It can be only done in a constructor, method or block scope. "Main" is not a class, it is a method inside of the Program class.

In your case usually used  "private" instead of var, also it is usually used with readonly word

```
public class player
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, building> _ownedbuildings = buildingDict.InitializeBuildings();

    public void purchasebuilding()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"There are {_ownedbuildings.Count} buildings for sale");
        Console.WriteLine($"{_ownedbuildings["wheatfield"].name} is sold at ${_ownedbuildings["wheatfield"].price}");
    }
}
```

but this will be working

```
public class player
{
    public void purchasebuilding()
    {
        var _ownedbuildings = buildingDict.InitializeBuildings();
        Console.WriteLine($"There are {_ownedbuildings.Count} buildings for sale");
        Console.WriteLine($"{_ownedbuildings["wheatfield"].name} is sold at ${_ownedbuildings["wheatfield"].price}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Serge, again I'm new so I forgot to think about the scope of declaring the variable within the purchasebuilding() method.  Which obviously works.